# What is the expectation value of the product of two random variables each with expectation zero?

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$. I want to show that $$(\mathbb{E}[XY])^2\leq \mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}(Y^2).$$

I've considered the following so far:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(\mathbb{E}[XY])^2 & = \Big(\sum_i\sum_jx_iy_jP(X=x_i, Y=y_j)\Big)^2 \\
& = ... + \sum_i\sum_jx_i^2y_j^2P(X=x_i, Y=y_j)^2 ... \\
\implies (\mathbb{E}[XY])^2 & \geq \sum_i\sum_jx_i^2y_j^2P(X=x_i, Y=y_j)^2. 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Also,

$$\mathbb{E}(X^2)\mathbb{E}(Y^2) = \sum_ix_i^2P(X=x_i)\sum_jy_j^2P(Y=y_j).$$

I can't see whether or not this has actually got me anywhere. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the *Cauchy-Schwarz inequality*.

Comment: The shortest route, not assuming in one hidden way or another that the result is already known, might be to note that the quadratics $$E((X+tY)^2)=E(Y^2)t^2+2E(XY)t+E(X^2)$$ is nonnegative for every real number $t$, hence its discriminant (you know, the famous $b^2-4ac$...) is nonpositive, that is, $$(2E(XY))^2-4E(X^2)E(Y^2)\leqslant0$$ which is your result. No need to assume discrete random variables, nor PDFs, nothing... And expectation zero is not required.

Comment: @Did Well, that’s cute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Var(X) = \mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}X)^2 = \mathbb{E} [X ^ 2]$, same for the $Y$, $Var(Y) = \mathbb{E} [Y ^ 2]$. Also recall that 
$$
f_X(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy
$$
and 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy = \int_{\mathbb{R}} dx\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_X(x)dx \, .
$$
   So, by the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality 
\begin{align}
(\mathbb{E}XY)^2 &= \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}xyf(x,y)dxdy \right) ^ 2\\
&\le \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}x ^ 2 f(x,y)dxdy   \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}y ^ 2 f(x,y)dxdy\\ 
&\le\int_{\mathbb{R}} x ^ 2f(x)dx \int_{\mathbb{R}} y ^ 2f(y)dx\\
 &= \mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y^2]. 
\end{align}

Basically, you don't even need these integrals, the conclusion is just a straightforward application of the inequality.

Another approach. 
Define the inner product $\langle X, Y \rangle =\mathbb{E}XY $, hence by Cauchy-Schwartz inequality you have 
$$
(\mathbb{E}XY)^2 = |\langle X, Y \rangle | ^ 2 \le  \langle X, X \rangle    \langle Y, Y \rangle  = \mathbb{E}( X ^ 2 ) \mathbb{E} (Y ^ 2) .
$$

Comment: Thanks but I've pretty much already written that answer in my question. I wrote $$E[XY])^2=\Big(\sum_i\sum_jx_iy_jP(x_i,y_j)\Big)^2$$ and $$E[X^2]E[Y^2] = \sum_ix_i^2P(x_i)\sum_jy_j^2P(y_j)$$ $$\implies E[XY]^2 = \Big(\sum_i\sum_jx_iy_jP(x_i,y_j)\Big)^2 \leq  \sum_ix_i^2P(x_i)\sum_jy_j^2P(y_j) = E[X^2]E[Y^2]$$ which is pretty much exactly your answer. What I'm looking for is how the inequality is proved.

Comment: I recognise that the proof of that inequality looks very similar to the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, as pointed out in the comment on the question. However, does the $P(x,y)$, $P(x)$, $P(y)$ not cause this to be somewhat different to the Schwartz Inequality?

Comment: If $f(x,y) = f(x) f(y)$ then the LHS is $0$ and the inequality trivially holds, for any other case the LHS is the ineer product $\langle X, Y \rangle $ which is defined $\mathbb{E} XY$, i.e., expectation of $XY$ w.r.t to $f(x,y)$.

Comment: Particularly, you can view the RHS as (for each variable) as $$ \int_x \int_y x^2 f(x,y)dxdy = \int x ^ 2 f(x)dx$$ as $ \int_y f(x,y) dy = f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $E(XY)=\sigma_{XY}$, the covariance between $X$ and $Y$, $E(X^2)=\sigma^2_X$ and $E(Y^2)=\sigma^2_Y$ their variances. Now $\frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}$, the correlation between them, is known to be a number between $-1$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$-1\le Corr(X,Y)=\frac{Var(X,Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)\cdot Var(Y)}}\le 1 \iff \\
-\sqrt{Var(X)\cdot Var(Y)}\le Var(X,Y)\le \sqrt{Var(X)\cdot Var(Y)} \iff \\
0\le [Var(X,Y)]^2\le Var(X)\cdot Var(Y) \iff \\
0\le \left(\mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E(X))(Y-\mathbb E(Y))]\right)^2\le \mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E(X))^2]\cdot \mathbb E[(Y-\mathbb E(Y))^2] \iff \\
\left(\mathbb E[XY]-\mathbb E(X)\mathbb E(Y)\right)^2\le (\mathbb E(X^2)-(\mathbb E(X))^2)(\mathbb E(Y^2)-(\mathbb E(Y))^2) \iff \\
(\mathbb E(XY))^2\le \mathbb E(X^2)\mathbb E(Y^2).$$